# Is NFC ACR1222U with built in Secure Access Module (SAM) compatible with Android phones?

Tags: android, nfc, galaxy, samsung-mobile, nfc-p2p

Does anyone have an idea if NFC card readers such as ACR1222U with built in Secure Access Module (SAM) are supported by Android NDEF PUSH / ANDROID BEAM? I found an interesting site which provides a Java Applet that connects to an NFC Reader and outputs all the NDEF Messages that are being transferred from the Android phone. Website: http://www.grundid.de/nfc/

In the applet example the card reader used is ACR122U and it works flawlessly. So is the ACR1222U (SAM) that different? My device is Samsung Galaxy SIII with Android 4.0.4 ICS.

Comment: As you seem to have all the necessary hardware, I would expect that you would be able to try for yourself and tell about the result (a specific error, for example).

Comment: The only thing that happens is that as soon as I place my phone on top of the card reader. The card reader starts to beep constantly and flashing its red light. That is all I get. If I try to beam something from the phone to the device nothing happens same story if you try the other way round, just a constant beeping sound and the red led light flashing.

P.S I also tried this with a Samsung Nexus 7 and got the same result.

Comment: I tried to debug this issue with an applet example I found on the Internet http://www.grundid.de/nfc/ndef-applet.html this shows that the device has a status of waiting and as soon as I place the mobile device on top of the NFC card reader, this starts to return a status of Disconnected and Waiting again and it keeps on going like this. To me it seems like that the two devices are trying to pair but for some reason to me unknown they loose the connection instantly.I have sent an email to the manufacturer. So far I didn't get any useful feedback. I will keep you posted with their reply. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you know the Firmeware Version of both ACR122Us? 
I experienced simmilar behaivour with an ACR122U 207 (without SAM) an the Galaxy S3.

I think the Problem is not related to the SAM Modul, because I've got it working here with a touchatag ACR122U with SAM Module and an older Firmeware Version.

After some research I found out that you have to put the reader into Initalizer Mode before you put the phone on it, otherwise there is some low level communication between reader and phone (Card Removed and Card present changing fast). Unfortunately there is nothing about it in the documentation by acr, but putting it in Initalizator mode and then putting the phone on it works on my side.

I am currently adding this to my [Android Beam API](http://code.google.com/p/java-android-beam-api/) and hopefully will finish during the next month.

Comment: Hello Woley I tried to use your API and used the following code to put the reader into initialize mode:  


    private void initCardReader(){
     TouchATag touchAtag = new TouchATag();
     try {
   touchAtag.initalizeWithDefaultValues();
  } catch (NFCInitalizationException e1) {
   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
   e1.printStackTrace();
  }
  try {
   touchAtag.start();
  } catch (NFCException e) {
   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
    }

But I am getting: Reader not supported! Please connect Touch a Tag Reader 

Any clue?  
Thanks

Comment: Hey can you try to execude this [Sample](http://code.google.com/p/java-android-beam-api/wiki/mixed#Firmeware_Version_via_direct_connect) to get your Firmeware Version. This will only work with Windows and the newer Firmewares, but it will be a hint if the Reader supports direct connection.

Comment: Hi woley and thanks for the reply. direct is supported. I checked and I also managed to send commands to the card reader (turn on and off antenna) using the transmitControlCommand(..) function. What I would really be interested in is a simple example on how to set the card reader to be ready to get NFC beamed messages from an android device (init mode?). And to beam a simple message and let say output a simple string message in the console. something like log.d(beamedMsg). That would be great :)

Comment: Yes that's on my ToDo List for my Android Beam API mentioned above :) (propably for the 1th quarter of the new year) you have to implement the full llcp, snep handshake to receive something. The first step is to put the reader into Initiator Mode, a good starting point for this is the tecnical documentations on the [acr homepage](http://www.acs.com.hk/index.php)

Comment: awesome thanks a lot :) . BTW any clue why the direct connection is required after upgrading from Android 4.0.4 to 4.1.2? In my opinion it is something related to how the NFC chipset works, but what is it exactly? What I am sure of is that once you upgrade .. you cannot revert back unless your phone is rooted. I mean if for instance you have a Nexus S and you downgrade to Android 2.3.6 from Factory Images for Nexus Devices https://developers.google.com/android/nexus/images the phone will boot up properly, however the NFC radio won't even start!

Comment: Its like the NFC chipset is upgraded with its own firmware which is not directly linked with the phone's rom. Once you downgrade to a previous rom (let say 2.3.6) the NFC firmware change persists! it is very annoying.

Comment: That is a big mistery for me as well! I tried downgrading my galaxy nexus to 4.0.4 from 4.1.1 but the NFC related stuff didn't change. There is something like a NFC.apk but I don't know how to flash a new one.

Comment: ahh and by the way I am trying to build up a comunity around the Android Beam topic and our API. Feel free to join the [Google Group here](http://groups.google.com/group/java-android-beam-api) , not that much members right now.

Comment: ahh cool thanks .. it is nice to share stuff like this as it is quite new and Google are constantly upgrading and changing protocols.